# Could not disabled select box as per check box checked using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I could not disable field as per check box checked or not using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="status"  id="status" ng-model="status" ng-disbaled="!$scope.ochkpancard && !$scope.ochkadhar">
                <option value="">Select Status</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
<div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><input id="ochkpancard" type="checkbox" ng-model="ochkpancard" /> Pancard</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><input id="ochkadhar" type="checkbox" ng-model="ochkadhar" /> Aadhar Card</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here I need when check box is not checked the select box will remain disabled and when the check boxes will be checked the select box will be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="status"  id="status" ng-model="status" ng-disabled="!(ochkpancard && ochkadhar)">
                <option value="">Select Status</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
<div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><input id="ochkpancard" type="checkbox" ng-model="ochkpancard" /> Pancard</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><input id="ochkadhar" type="checkbox" ng-model="ochkadhar"/> Aadhar Card</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```